# php extract method not parsing dashes in key name

Tags: php

I have a array given below:

```
$var_array = array("g-recaptcha-response" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
```

i want to get each key as variable. so i am using php's `extract` function :

```
extract($var_array);
```

but when i print values of each variable it provides following output:

```
echo $size;
echo "\n";
echo $shape;
echo "\n";
echo $g-recaptcha-response;
```

output:

```
medium
sphere
0
```

instead of :

```
medium
sphere
blue
```

Comment: I know what PHP variable naming conventions are, what i wanted to know - is there a way to achieve it without changing my variable name, because some how i can not change the name of array key? why down vote??

Answer (score 2):

"-" wont work most probably, try using "_" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Rules for PHP variables:

```
A variable starts with the $ sign, followed by the name of the variable
A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character
A variable name cannot start with a number
A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
Variable names are case-sensitive ($age and $AGE are two different variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP variables can't contain hypens `-`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Variables**

A variable can have a short name (like x and y) or a more descriptive name (age, carname, total_volume).

Rules for PHP variables:

```
A variable starts with the $ sign, followed by the name of the variable
A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character
A variable name cannot start with a number
A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
Variable names are case-sensitive ($age and $AGE are two different variables)
```

So you variable `$g-recaptcha-response;` is wrong, try `$gRecaptchaResponse;` and your array :

```
$var_array = array("gRecaptchaResponse" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $var_array = array("g_recaptcha_response" => "blue",
               "size"  => "medium",
               "shape" => "sphere");
               extract($var_array);
               echo $size;             //medium
               echo "\n";
               echo $shape;           //  sphere 
               echo "\n";
               echo $g_recaptcha_response;  //blue
               ?
```